# Cassandra - aggregate timestamp by hour

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table with timestamps in a 15 min interval. It's possible to aggregate or group by **hour** and the `load` field being the average?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a [post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views) on materialized views. You can use it to create a copy of data batched by hour. Then use the average aggregate functions on load. I think [CASSANDRA-11871](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11871) Is what your looking for though, which has all its dependancies in `group by` has recently been completed but hasnt been worked on yet.

Kinda just guessing on your schema but something like (disclaimer not really tested):

```
CREATE TABLE load (
 ref_equip text,
 ptd_assoc text,
 date timestamp,
 date_hour bigint,
 load float,
 PRIMARY KEY ((ref_equip, ptd_assoc), date)
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW load_by_hour AS 
SELECT * FROM load 
WHERE ref_equip IS NOT NULL AND ptd_assoc IS NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY ((ref_equip, ptd_assoc), date_hour, date);
```

where date_hour is just the timestamp with hour resolution, meaning divide by 1000*60*60 (epoc is ms) when doing insert. Can then select average

```
SELECT avg(load) FROM load_by_hour WHERE ref_equip='blarg' AND ptd_assoc='blargy' AND date_hour = 410632;
```

Alternatively something that may just be better to begin with is to store you data, partitioned by hour:

```
CREATE TABLE load (
 ref_equip text,
 ptd_assoc text,
 date timestamp,
 date_hour bigint,
 load float,
 PRIMARY KEY ((ref_equip, ptd_assoc, date_hour), date)
);
```

Comment: Humm, i understand the use of a materialized view but i can't understand how can you manage to transform `date` field into an aggregate of date by hour with the field load being the average of the 4*15min... :/

Comment: Basically from what i understand the `load` table already have the date_hour defined, you just use the view to query the average, right? So, before i insert the data into `load` table i have to divide the timestamp already in ms by 1000*60*60..?

Comment: date_hour is to bucket the data (you dont want infinite growing partitions) and to provide a key for the MV to build off of. Create it by just dividing timestamp exactly. Then to query for it or a range of them you just have to do that conversion to know partitions to read from

Comment: Did it! Thank you Chris! Good solution